# CQ ResourceResolver from external app?

Tags: aem

Is it possible to get reference to ResourceResolver from external app i.e. not deployed in CQ? Is it possible to use it to fetch Resource, AssetManagers, etc?

We have to create DAM Assets using an external application and would want a better solution than using JCR API for this. One way would be to host an osgi Service on CQ and call it using REST to create the assets but it would be cleaner if the code for creating assets was part of the app itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to get a handle of ResourceResolver in your external app. The ResourceResolver handle or reference can only be obtained when your app is running inside OSGi.

If you are writing an external app then you can use only lower level JCR API(ResourceResolver is part of sling API).